# « Faire le poireau, poiroter » : quel poireau, pourquoi ?

Tags: sens, argot, origine-ou-raison, lexique

On a [*poireauter*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poireauter), *poiroter*, le verbe intransitif, familier, signifiant « attendre sans changer de place, faire le [poireau](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poireau) », [de](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/poireauter) [*faire le*] *poireau* justement (TLFi) :

> Il [le poireau] a développé, par analogie de forme, le sens [...] de « verrue » (1487) d'usage populaire, et ultérieurement celui de « pénis » (1867) d'usage argotique (Cf. asperge). La locution familière usuelle ***faire le poireau*** (1877), ***rester planté
>   comme un poireau*** « attendre » a été précédée par *planter son poireau*
>   (1867) et s'ordonne par métaphore à *poireau* « légume » avec la valeur
>   figurée d'« être planté là » (Cf. ci-dessous *poireauter*). Cependant,
>   selon P. Guiraud, cette métaphore sur « planter » serait seconde ; comme
>   *cor au pied* et *point de côté* désignaient en argot ancien des
>   surveillants, *poireau* « verrue » avait aussi ce sens plaisant, réalisé
>   régionalement dans *porion*.
>  Le seul derivé de poireau est le
>   familier **poireauter** (1880) verbe intransitif, avec un *t* épenthétique, «
>   attendre ».
>
> [ *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (DHLF), sup. A.Rey,
>   *Le Robert*, 2012, « poireau ». ]

- En sait-on davantage aujourd'hui et sur quel sens au juste du
  *poireau* et de ce qu'il fait repose l'expression *faire le poireau* et le verbe *poireauter* ?
- Pourquoi serait-ce le *poirot* qui est « planté là » et pas la
  carotte ou la betterave etc. ; est-ce la popularité du poireau ou son
  emploi argotique qui oriente le choix de légumes dans les métaphores
  qui en contiennent (y réfèrent) comme celle-ci ; peut-on confimer que le verbe relève du registre familier ?

Comment: Il n'y a pas que le poireau, on peut très bien être **planté comme un chou** !

Comment: Voilà @jlliagre qui...  *chouxotte*... hmmm... *choussaille*... hmmm *chouxoye*... Ha! J'y suis! Qui **Brassicaille** maintenant! Top! Je fonce! ©® 2018 aCOSwt : jlliagre : Quand cesserez-vous donc de *brassicailler* :-)

Comment: @aCOSwt Ne me **prend pas le chou** ! ;p

Comment: @jlliagre : Des nèfles! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Je me trouve hic&nunc un poil *hasbeen* pour répondre à votre première question. Et comme en plus elle ne m'intéresse pas... je la laisserai à d'autres.
Après...

- Pourquoi un poireau et pas une betterave ou une carotte :

Il me semble que l'on peut dire sans trop s'avancer que la visibilité de l'objet planté semble être une propriété... décisive ! non ?

Mais qu'on se rassure ! Le poireau ne détient pas le monopole dans les expressions de même sens tant on peut se trouver aussi *planté comme un piquet*, voire... ce qui m'arrivait quand je me faisais gronder par mes parents dont la bibliothèque était plus riche en références que le potager... : rester *planté là comme un I*. <sup>3</sup>

Je dirais donc bien, pour commencer la réponse à la seconde question que l'objet de la plantation dépend beaucoup de... ce dont on dispose principalement en référence... ce avec quoi on est... bref ! *familier* quoi ! ;-) 
Pour commencer seulement car, pour entrer dans le détail :

**A/ *Poireauter* appartient sans aucun doute au langage familier.**

C'est bien la première fois que je m'autorise d'être aussi péremptoire dans un jugement catégorique et ce pourrait être osé sachant que les contours du *langage familier* ont beaucoup changé depuis 1880...

Ont beaucoup changé certes mais cela ne fait rien... toutes <sup>1</sup> les études savantes portant sur le langage familier, d'il y a très longtemps à nos jours, malgré la définition de périmètres différents, retiennent *poireauter / faire le poireau* dans leur corpus de référence. <sup>2</sup>

**B/ Non ! Ce n'est pas la popularité du poireau ou son emploi argotique qui oriente le choix.**

Enfin... pas immédiatement.

Benveniste distingue le sens sémantique du discours et le sens sémiotique de la langue. Eh bien la familiarité lexicale, elle vient d'une rupture, d'une cassure, d'une disjonction entre les deux. Jean Cohen parle d'*[impertinence du prédicat](https://www.persee.fr/doc/lgge_0458-726x_1968_num_3_12_2351)*, je dirais d'une proposition absurde.
C'est, dans un premier temps, une dissonance cognitive entre le sens lexical de l'objet et les propriétés connues du sujet qui oriente le choix.

Or, en restant dans le cadre du vivant... que peut-on trouver de plus éloigné de l'homme qu'un... légume ? Et, dans le cas qui nous préoccupe ici d'un verbe de manière, c'est bien à dire dont le sujet accomplit le procès *à la façon de*, que trouver de plus... péjoratif ?

Bon... certains pourraient suggérer le règne animal... *cochonner, canarder, fouiner, pigeonner, cornaquer...* Oui ! Il est assurément riche en ressources familières ! Quoique... vous le noterez c'est tout de même significativement moins péjorant.

Car le côté péjoratif importe ici évidemment... d'autant... qu'on va balancer une seconde couche pour bien enfoncer le clou : le suffixe ! *-oter* (phonétiquement) 
Pfffiuu ! C'est très péjo ça -oter en suffixe de verbe de manière. Plus ? peut-être peut-on trouver -ouiller / -oyer... mais... c'est souvent plus gentil.

Et là, quand on en est à suffixer -oter... on trouve quoi ? *patatoter* ? bof ! *carotter* ? c'est déjà pris pour autre chose, Betteravotter ? Bof !

Bref *poireau*... c'est assez commode en finale non ?

Ha... *artichauter* aurait aussi pu le faire ! (vite !... Copyright 2018 aCOSwt) :-)

<sub>1 : Toutes ? Enfin... on dira beaucoup car... je l'avoue... je ne les connais pas toutes...</sub>

<sub>2 : Parlant du cas général du lexique familier, on pourrait aussi s'amuser à un vulgaire comptage de la marque *FAM.* dans les PL et PR ed. 2002 (Pourquoi 2002 ? Parce que je m'y suis amusé et qu'après ça ne m'amusait plus) qui démontrerait une distribution semblable dans plus des 3/4 des cas (le quart restant étant principalement le fait de non-hexagonalismes et formes vieillies) alors que... alors que les lexicographes avouaient ne pas suivre des critères formels...</sub>

<sub>3 : Sans compter l'emploi pronominal tant il m'arrivera, plus tard, à l'École de... *me planter comme une buse* ! ;-)</sub>

Comment: J'avais pensé au suffixe, aussi, en réfléchissant à cette question. J'avais rassemblé... roulement de tambour s’il vous plaît... **vivoter** et **barbotter**... Bon, c'est pas grand'chose, et c'est plus oral qu'orthographique (à cause du double T de barbotter), mais ces deux-là donnaient déjà une impression de laisser-aller un peu désinvolte et mou, sans grande volonté de quelque chose... et puis, il y a aussi la **gargotte**, qui ne nous donne que l’énergie d'y aller poser notre... machin... et d’y pratiquer le sport pas trop olympique du lever du coude.

Comment: @Montéedelait mon vieux pote**au**! Oui! L'apport sémantique du suffixe est indéniable. Mais attention toutefois : Si, dans les cas de poireau, ceux que vous citez et auxquels ont pourrait ajouter *megoter, cocotter, tournicoter...* la valeur péjorative ne fait pas de doute, elle n'est cependant pas aussi systématique que cela. -oter peut aussi prendre une valeur diminutive / fréquentative... et ç'est là qu'on commence à s'aventurer dans un domaine que j'avais justement cherché à éviter dans ma réponse parce qu'un poil *touchy* : Le préjugé social!. HIPS! Pardon! Fallait pas m'inviter! ;-)

Comment: Pas sûr que le lien entre poireauter et le suffixe -ot- me convainque, vu la différence de voyelle entre les deux. Il me semble plus probable que le -t- de poireauter soit analogue à celui de chouchouter, de dodoter et de blablater: une simple consonne de transition rajoutée aux racines à finale vocalique quand on forme spontanément un verbe à partir d'un nom

Comment: Votre doute est légitime. Un *t épenthétique* est effectivement concevable si ce n'est certain. Mais je crois cette épenthèse co-incidente. Un "ça tombe bien" dans l'écriture de ce que je tiens toujours pour un suffixe en toute autonomie car... n'oblitérons pas que l'orthographe la plus courante pour le *poir**eau**ter* pris dans le sens de l'OP est bien *poir**o**ter*.

Comment: @aCOSwt … certains soutiennent que l’***eau*** serait largement préférable pour les poi[v]r***o***t : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poireauter%2Cpoiroter&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpoireauter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoiroter%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @cl-r : !lol! À la tienne cl-r! Qu'est-ce que le premier commentaire de ex-montée-de-lait a pu faire vider de bouteilles! J'en reviens pas!... Bon HIPS! Pardon! Yop! Objection retenue!... pour la forme plaisante. (Le fond étant nuancé par le fait qu'avec des taux de 5 pour 1 million vu le corpus de référence... j'ai tendance à penser que cela ne représente pas beaucoup d'exemples et que la conclusion que l'on pourrait tirer de cela serait à prendre avec des pincettes). Tu dirais quoi toi d'un alcool à 5 pour 1 million ? :-)

Comment: @aCOSwt — de la bibine, de la pisse d’âne… ou plutôt une bière sans alcool [il y en a quand même dans le flacon … encore une publicité loyale], rien à voir avec un cognac *XO*, ou mieux, *hors-d’age* oublié dans la cave d’une petite maison entre la ville où la part des anges noircit les murs et La Rochelle.