# Le substantif « poireautage » est-il un régionalisme ?

Tags: québec, régionalismes, registre-familier, linguistique

Le TLFi identifie le substantif masculin [*poireautage*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poireautage) signifiant le fait de [*poireauter*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poireauter) (voir une autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/32222)) comme un régionalisme du Canada. Le DHLF précise que c'est de 1950 pour le « fait d'attendre longtemps » (DHLF) sans mentionner s'il s'agit ou non d'un régionalisme.

S'agit-il d'un régionalisme ; peut-on préciser, donner un ou des exemples pour illustrer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il existe, surtout dans la presse imprimée il est vrai, des attestations du terme en terre de France datant du début du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle.

À tout seigneur tout honneur, voici le grand humoriste Alphonse Allais :

> » Et surtout quand ma brave petite galette tombe ès mains crochues d’un sous-financier résolument insouriant, intermédiaire entre l’Etat-gouffre et les pauvres diables de contribuables.
>   » Ajoutons à ces détresses l’ennui résultant du dérangement, du **poireautage** en des bureaux plutôt moroses et souvent miasmiques.
>   » En un mot, tout cela n’est pas drôle.
>        *<sub>—Alphonse ALLAIS in Le journal (Paris), 7 avril 1905</sub>*

D’autres suivirent, pendant de nombreuses années. Si ce n’est pas une expression commune, ce n’est pas non plus un phénomène de mode ou passager, sitôt arrivé sitôt disparu :

> Mais laissons tous ces personnages fictifs, je n’en veux pas à Anna, car elle m’a un jour révèle la cause de ces **poireautages** que j’avais fini par trouver indispensables. Je me souviens même fort bien qu’un mardi — voyez si j’ai bonne mémoire, je précise — assis sur une marche de l’escalier, je n’avais pas achevé *l’Histoire de France* du père Thiers, quand Anna vint plus vite que je ne l’avais craint... eh bien, je dus la renvoyer et n’entrai dans l’appartement qu’après avoir terminé l’oeuvre du célèbre homme d’Etat.
>        *<sub>—L’Impatient, Félix GALIPAUX in Le Pêle-mêle : journal humoristique hebdomadaire (Paris), février 1917</sub>*

---

> Si mon sourire habituel ne suffit pas à ces dames employées, toujours très occupées dès la rentrée, aux artifices de leur coquetterie ou au petit bout de causette habituel, pour m’éviter la réponse « Il n’est pas l’heure », je ferai jouer mon déclic et peut-être réussirai-je à abréger un **poireautage** prolongé.
>       *<sub>—Le Grand écho de l’Aisne : organe hebdomadaire d’informations et de défense des intérêts généraux de la région, 5 novembre 1921</sub>*

---

> « Encore une heure de **poireautage**, disait un des soldats, un gradé sans doute, aux premières heures du jour, nous déguerpissons, que la ronde soit passée ou non. »
>        *<sub>—Le Sidérateur, Jules HOCHE, roman inédit in L’Intransigeant (Paris), 15 juin 1925</sub>*

Il semble que le terme ait depuis trouvé un terreau (très) fertile au Québec, et qu’il soit demeuré plus marginal ailleurs. Est-ce là la définition que l’on doit donner à *régionalisme* ? Si un contraste à la mesure de celui-ci suffit, alors oui, c’est un régionalisme.

Mais si le terme considéré se doit d’être exclusif à une région, et préférablement de provenir de ladite région pour être considéré comme une régionalisme, alors on ne saurait affirmer que c’en est un.

On pourrait encore dire que ce que le terme est devenu au Canada français ne donne plus beaucoup à penser qu’il est lié au poireau : l’orthographe alternative du verbe lié est plus fidèle à la prononciation québécoise (poiroter [pwɛʁɔte]). On pourrait de la même manière imaginer un « poirotage » qui représentât mieux le [pwɛʁɔtaʒ] prononcé à la québécoise. Peut-être cette prononciation est-elle particulière au Québec, mais peut-être pas non plus, puisque ***poiroter*** n’est **pas** désigné comme régionalisme au TLFi, la source pourtant de la désignation régionale du dérivé ***poireautage***.

Mais au final, je ne m’y connais pas suffisamment pour trancher la question, et la laisserai donc en suspens. Libre à d’autres d’y apporter la réponse qui convient.

Comment: Bravo! Vous avez là posé **toutes** les **bonnes questions** en résolvant la dernière d'une manière aussi commode qu'élégante : Rompre le lien d'une trop rigoureuse et bien embarrassante homonymie. BRAVO! donc et puisse mon vote compter double!

Answer (score 2):

Pour faire court, je resterai ici et maintenant sur la réserve qu'affiche le DHLF.

Je dirai qu'il ne s'agit ici que de ***variante lexicale***.

Variante lexicale d'un même lexème.

Aller au délà ? Whou! On peut s'y risquer mais il faut alors faire intervenir des critères non seulement topologiques mais aussi (comme on peut le deviner suite à l'intervention de *Montée_de_lait*) chronologiques quand ce n'est pas... sémantiques...!

Pour ce cas particulier de *poireautage* ET, dans le cas général des *régionalismes* j'ai préféré entrer, à ma façon, dans ces considérations et arguments [ici](http://chasseautresor-ng.0707a.net/forum/index.php?topic=242.0).

<sub>NDaCOSwt : J'ai bien noté dans votre question la préférence donnée à l'expression de ***régionalisme du Canada***. Venant de vous, elle m'interroge :</sub>
<sub>- Considérez-vous, comme cela en a été l'usage par le passé, que le français canadien désigne le français du Québec, ou alors</sub>
<sub>- Tiendriez-vous déjà le français québécois, le français acadien, le français ontarien, le français de l'Ouest canadien pour des *variétés* de français canadien ?</sub>
<sub>Dans ce dernier cas, je n'aurais évidemment strictement rien à vous apprendre sur les concepts de *régionalisme* et de *variation lexicale* que vous ne sachiez déjà... mieux que moi.</sub>

Comment: La discussion liée est intéressante, et explicite bien une démarche qui définira plusieurs paramètres avant de conclure. On peut en effet sortir de la norme de plusieurs manières: en changeant de région, en changeant d'époque, en changeant de registre, en changeant de milieu social, etc. Tenter de caser ce qui est et n'est pas un régionalisme dans cet amas de paramètres peut en effet être laborieux, et donner un nom particulier à un phénomène linguistique demande une certaine réflexion. Merci d'avoir partagé le fruit de vos réflexions, fut-ce à un lien d'écart.

Comment: @Montéedelait : ... et... milieu social! Vous aurez noté que... je ne l'avais pas évoqué celui-là et, vous avez raison, il serait à considérer. Mais... je le laisse volontiers aux socio-linguistes. J'ai pour ma part toujours **voulu croire** que la puissance de l'École publique, laïque et obligatoire aurait raison des différences sociales dans leur expression linguistique... encore une décision arbitraire... celle *d'un vieux barbu qui, dans sa caverne, ne sait pas encore que Dieu est mort* sans doute ;-)

Comment: J'avais redouté que ce soit interprété comme une hiérarchie verticale, alors que j'avais en tête des bulles d'huile flottant à la surface d'une flaque d'eau. Les termes employés ne seront pas les mêmes quand je travaille ou quand je parle de mon métier à quelqu'un qui ne connaît pas ce milieu. Mais il demeure indéniable que le fait que vous invoquez, une certaine hiérarchie verticale, existe aussi.

Comment: @Montéedelait : Rassurez-vous! J'avais bien compris votre intention. Mais... attention... si vous n'y prenez garde... relativement au *vieux barbu dans sa caverne*, vous allez passer de Pandore à... Zarathoustra! ;-)